# Not enough space between name and rep in questions list on MSE

Tags: bug, design

Today I noticed this squished spacing on the [main questions list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=recentlyactive) (using the new navigation with defaults) here on MSE:

[image: MSE screenshot]

The space between the name (and optional diamond) and the reputation number is smaller than on other sites and, I think, smaller than it was a week or so ago.  I've circled a couple cases that look particularly bad with this styling.  In all my screenshots I've attempted to include both diamond and regular users, and reps with and without collapsing (up to 4 digits is given exactly; after it's, e.g., "10.7k").

I don't see this spacing problem on The Workplace, which has the new base CSS:

[image: Workplace screenshot]

And I don't see it on Mi Yodeya, which is still awaiting the CSS update:

[image: Mi Yodeya screenshot]

So the spacing isn't *only* due to new-versus-old CSS, and that might be a red herring.  MSE is the only site that has the new navigation (right?), so I'm not sure how to test that variable.

Anyway, whatever's causing it, it looks kind of weird.  If it only occurs on MSE then that's minor, but if it's caused by something that's being tested on MSE before being rolled out to the whole network, we might want to fix it.

Comment: @James I couldn't find it, but if it's a dupe that I missed I'll be happy to close it as such once we find it.

Comment: I've posted dupes before having spent *literally* 30 mins searching the site and Google with a gazillion keyword combinations.

Comment: @James yeah, I searched for a while first before spending the time to take and mark up the screenshots and write a fairly detailed description.  It does look like a dupe of a less-detailed question.  Pity I didn't find that before investing in the writeup here.  Oh well -- a dupe's a dupe.  Thanks for finding it.